# CDBException (error) handling in C++ (VS2010, MFC, Excel/ODBC)

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010, mfc, odbc

Beginner here.

I have an application built in MFC Vicual C++, compiled using VS2010. I have a DSN as an ODBC connection to a live Excel spreadsheet (via Excel driver).

My app queries a spreadsheet every second. If one cell's value changes (a result of a simple calculation involving other cells receiving a live data feed), the app prints the new value then goes back to querying for changes.

The App works fine for a period of time, dutifully printing the changes in the cell's value as new data arrives in the feed. Then, it invariably generates an error:

"The Microsoft Jet Engine could not find the object '(unknown)' Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

The file paths are all given in absolutes.

I surmise that the error is generated whenever the query happens to exactly coincide with the cell's contents being updated. I can generate the exact same error message and behavior, always, instantly, by clicking on the surveyed cell and touching a key (beginning to edit the cell, here by overtyping the cell formula).

An Afx error dialog runs. If I "OK" and select the excel file, the application goes back and runs, until a new same error. But if I select "Cancel" the application exits.

If I comment out my own error catch, this dialog still appears.

I would like the application to run "headless" and merely retry to connect with the database.

Is there any way I can override here?

I realize Excel is not amenable to concurrent (multiuser) access. But I don't need to have concurrent access- I don't care to see the cell when "something else" is changing it. I simply want to (wait and) retry.

Apologies in advance for asking about dinosaur bone-tech here. The fact I need to query live data has led me by trial-and-error to ODBC (libxl sees only the file data and formulas, rather than their values).

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `CDBException` like this:

```
    try
    {
        // DB calls
    }
    catch(CDBException *err)
    {
        // simply ignore the error
        err->Delete();
    }
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks, but I tried that. If I am typing in any cell in the spreadsheet when a query is made, the Jet error dialog still appears, and if I "Cancel" rather than re-point it at the Excel file the App exits. If I type "quickly" (under 1 second) the error never appears. It's something akin to: if you are editing a cell the file is invisible.

Comment: You need to provide the source code here. So we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got this to work.
Within the function, where the SQL executed, I caught the exception, destructed, then called "ExitThread()" rather than simply permit the App to proceed to exit. The thread invoking the function would terminate, but the App did not exit. I then placed the creation of this calling thread inside a work thread which tests every half-second to see if the calling thread is running, using WaitForSingleObject().  Within the calling thread I also added a check for the existence of the spreadsheet file, which always exists but may not appear visible to the App due to Excel's lack of support for concurrency.

So, you can query an Excel spreadsheet via ODBC from Visual C++ in an App that is robust to people accidentally touching a key in the spreadsheet or a cell update (here, from a market data feed) causing a nasty "non-existent link" error. It's not especially elegant, but it is fast and, so far, robust.